# create-react-app w/ TypeScript & Tailwind CSS; Tailwind's utility classes are not being applied

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I've been searching all over to try and resolve this issue. I created a React app with TypeScript and installed Tailwind CSS using the React setup shown on the Tailwind site [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app).

Below is my code and configuration. It runs successfully when I do a `npm run start`, but the Tailwind styles are not applied.

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="items-center justify-center">
    <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
      Testing
    </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

**index.css**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**postcss.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "mortgage-calc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.43",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.5"
  }
}
```

**My output**
[image: My output]

Comment: did you quit the server after installing tailwind? if not then then please restart it, maybe it will start working, I had the same problem

Comment: Yep, I've restarted it a few times just in case and I get the same thing. I've updated my post to show what I see when I do a npm run start.

Comment: try to change your tailwind config.js.  to this,                                                  module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Comment: Exactly what is mentioned on the official site you took reference from

Comment: Has no effect whatsoever, and adding the component portion is just scanning my components folder for styles as well.

Comment: I do get a ```Creating an optimized production build...

warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.``` when running npm run start

Comment: What's the full path to your `tailwind.config.js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the spaces between the file endings in your `tailwind.config.js`:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

If that doesn't correct your problem, try to remove the CSS import in your `App.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="items-center justify-center">
    <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
      Testing
    </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You're awesome! Nice catch, it was the spaces in the tailwind.config.js content.